# Does learning a spell through the Magic Initiate feat allow me to cast that spell from a spell scroll?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, feats

Bob the Fighter takes the Magic Initiate feat and selects *hex* as his once-per-day spell given by the feat.

Bob later finds a Spell Scroll of *hex*.

Can Bob use that spell scroll, or not?

Comment: Is Bob an Eldritch Knight?

Comment: Nah, Bob's a cheeky ol' Champion.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### No, Bob can't use that spell scroll

To cast a spell from a [*spell scroll*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/spell-scroll), it must be on your class spell list. Bob does not have *hex* on his spell list.

> If the spell is on your class’s spell list, you can read the scroll and cast its spell

The spell you learn from [Magic Initiate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/magic-initiate) is not added to a spell list. It gives you an alternative method to cast spells separate from Spellcasting and similar features.

> You learn that [1st-level] spell and can cast it at its lowest level.

Comment: You might want to include that the feat doesn't say the spells are added to your list, only that you can cast them.

Comment: @GreySage good point. Added

Comment: This is a correct RAW reading, and is concordant with Sage's answers to similar questions. That said, I'd absolutely allow it, as it seems silly not to. ^_^

Answer (score 6):

## Bob does not have a spell list

As [DavidCoffron](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/132040/35259) points out, "to cast a spell from a spell scroll, it must be on your class spell list."

> If the spell is on your class’s spell list, you can read the scroll and cast its spell [...] (DMG, pg. 200)

The Magic Initiate feat does not grant a spell list to a non-spellcasting class. It simply provides access to a spell (and two cantrips) from *a class's* spell list:

From PHB, pg. 168:

> Choose a class: bard, cleric, druid, sorcerer, warlock, or wizard. You learn two cantrips of your choice **from that class's spell list**.
>
> In addition, choose one 1st-level spell **from that same list**. [...]

Nowhere does it say that you have  a spell list now, since that's tied to classes; you simply have the cantrips and spell that you pick.

---

**Caveat:** This is assuming that Bob the Fighter doesn't choose the Eldritch Knight archetype, since that would give him access to the Wizard's spell list, which is effectively the Eldritch Knight's spell list. Of course, *hex* is not on the Wizard's spell list, so Magic Initiate *still* doesn't give you the ability to cast *hex* from a scroll.

Comment: Also, I don't see any RAW reason why, for example, a human Warlock can't take magic initiate to get an additional once-per-day Warlock spell, plus two more cantrips. ***Another*** class's spell list is not required. You get a spell from ***that*** class's spell list. Correct?

Comment: @Davo Wizards of the Coast's official rules clarification document, [Sage Advice](http://dnd.wizards.com/sage-advice-compendium) clarifies that you can take Magic Initiate for a class you have levels in. For a more detailed answer you should ask the question in its own post.

Comment: Thanks, no question other than questioning @NathanS's text indicating that Magic Initiate only allows cantrips and spells from ***another*** class's spell list. I edited the answer for clarity.

Comment: Ah yes, you were correct. I shouldn't have said another. Thanks for the edit.